# Connect to Windows 10 Hyper-V from Windows 7 (remote management)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hyper-v, remote-management

I have Hyper-V setup on a Windows 10 machine.  I want to enable remote management from my Windows 7 machine.  I have setup the same user account on both machines, but when I try to connect from Windows 7 Hyper-V, it says "The operation on computer 'Server' failed".

Any idea what else I can do to set this up?  I have searched and can't find instructions on setting up remote management for Hyper-V.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot manage Windows 10 Hyper-V from Windows 7. The MSDN article [Manage Remote Hyper-V Hosts with Hyper-V Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/remote_host_management) states that you need another Windows 10 client to do so:

> **Supported Hyper-V host combinations with Hyper-V Manager**
>
> Hyper-V Manager in Windows 10 allows you to manage the following
>   Hyper-V hosts:
>
> - Windows 10
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 + Windows Server Core, Datacenter, and Hyper-V Server
> - Windows 2012 + Windows Server Core, Datacenter, and Hyper-V Server
>
> Hyper-V Manager in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 allow you to
>   manage:
>
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 + Windows Server Core, Datacenter, and Hyper-V Server
> - Windows 2012 + Windows Server Core, Datacenter, and Hyper-V Server
>
> Hyper-V Manager in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 allow you to
>   manage:
>
> - Windows 8
> - Windows 2012 + Windows Server Core, Datacenter, and Hyper-V Server